# gzip -t in a loop and run script

Tags: python, bash, for-loop, gzip

I have several *.gz files in a folder, and I want to run a python script on them. However, I have been getting errors. These errors are associated with corrupted gz files.

I want run my python script **ONLY** in gz files correctly compressed. I have tried the following:

```
for i in *.gz;
do
    if gzip -t $i
    then
        python myscript.py
    else
        echo 'file is corrupt'
    fi
done;
```

But my script is being run also in corrupted gz files (and through a lot of errors).

Alternatively, Can I modified the python script to read only non-corrupted gz files?

The top of my current script is:

```
for tf in glob.glob('*.gz'):
    tar = tarfile.open(tf)
    tar.extractall()
    tar.close()
    files = [file for file in glob.glob('*.txt')] ..
```

If I open the gz files, I would like to keep it (cause I know gunzip will delete the original gz file while decompressing).

Thanks in advance

Comment: gunzip -k, keeps the input files intact, it doesn't delete them

Comment: @gusa10 : Did you ever try to manually `gunzip` an archive which you Python program claimed to be corrupt? My guess is that those archives are not really corrupt, but that the problem is in the Python code. In particular, I think you need [`gzip.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html), not `tarfile.open`

Comment: Yes, I cannot extract the files in those *.gz files anymore. Also, their size is smaller than expected. This is strange to me as I worked with these files before and everything was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
gunzip -t $i
```

instead, to check for corruption:

```
for i in *.gz;
do
    if gunzip -t $i
    then
        python myscript.py
    else
        echo 'file is corrupt'
    fi
done;
```

the default for gunzip is to decompress.

-t tests the file for integrity.

To do this all with bash:

```
for i in *.gz;
do
    if gunzip -t $i
    then
        gzip -d $1 # -d decompress
    else
        echo 'file is corrupt'
    fi
done;
```

gunzip keeps the origin files when you pass the -k option to it, -k for keep input files

Comment: Thanks @bhristov. However, it seems that the script is still being run for the corrupted files. The output error is still: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 8, in <module>
    tar.extractall() .........
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached.

Comment: @gusa10 you should use gunzip or gzip instead of tar to extract.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me a hand on this? I have modified the question.

Comment: @gusa10  can we use bash to do this? I think that it will be much easier.

Comment: Yes. I guess it will be a matter to start the python script after the gz is decompressed.

Comment: @gusa10 yes, I added a section to my answer for bash